# iOS: update a field in model any time managed object model gets modified

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a "last updated" field on my model. Any time a managed object model gets changed, I'd like that field to get updated. Is there any way I can have this happen automatically? Or do I need to just update that field manually when I make the other modifications?

Comment: Do you mean the model itself, or some entity object?

Comment: I mean the entity object.

Answer (score 0):

#### "Is there any way I can have this happen automatically?"

No. Core Data is not a database, it's an API for abstract object graph management. It has no concept of uniqueness, auto-incrementing values, etc.

#### "Or do I need to just update that field manually when I make the other modifications?"

Correct, for example having a `lastModified` property that your application sets with each change.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of some delegate on NSManagedObject that might get called any time the object is saved. I guess I could use something like KVO, right?

Answer (score -1):

You could KVO all keys in your entity but maybe this is not necessary. I would suggest you only update the `lastUpdated` property when you actually save the object because before that you could still just throw away the changes (either on purpose or e.g. because the app terminates).

Therefore, you can simply override `willSave`. This is specifically designed for this kind of situation (it mentions a "last-modified" attribute), but note the caveats mentioned in the documentation

> If you want to update a persistent property value, you should typically test for equality of any new value with the existing value before making a change. If you change property values using standard accessor methods, Core Data will observe the resultant change notification and so invoke willSave again before saving the object’s managed object context. If you continue to modify a value in `willSave`, `willSave` will continue to be called until your program crashes.
>
> For example, if you set a last-modified timestamp, you should check whether either you previously set it in the same save operation, or that the existing timestamp is not less than a small delta from the current time. Typically it’s better to calculate the timestamp once for all the objects being saved (for example, in response to an `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`).